# how can i get a value of sqlite and then update it

Tags: python, sqlite

Using Python and Sqlite3
How can I fetch a value from sqlite, store it in a variable then add a string to it and update it ?

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("intel.db")
database   = connection.cursor()

u                   = 'Zero'
all     = database.execute("SELECT * FROM logs")
newtext = ' message.content '

for w in all:
    if u in w[1]:
        print("exist")
        olddata = database.execute("SELECT logtext FROM logs where loguser=? ", (u))

        ## use olddata + newtext then add to updated 

        updated = database.execute("UPDATE logs SET logtext = ? WHERE loguser = ?", (olddata + newtext, u,))
        print("User textlog updated")
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need to know the correct syntax, below I created a new db, and insert two records data, and then get the value from db and update it:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('intel.db')
database = conn.cursor()
database.execute('''CREATE TABLE logs
             (date text, logtext text, loguser text, qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
database.execute("INSERT INTO logs VALUES ('2006-01-05','HI','Zero',100,35.14)")
database.execute("INSERT INTO logs VALUES ('2006-01-03','HELLO','David',100,35.14)")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

u = 'Zero'
all_data = database.execute("SELECT * FROM logs")
newtext = ' message.content '
for w in all_data:
    if u in w:
        print("exist")
        olddata = database.execute("SELECT logtext FROM logs where loguser=? ", (u,)).fetchone()[0]
        print "Old Data:"
        print olddata
        database.execute("UPDATE logs SET logtext = ? WHERE loguser = ?", (olddata + newtext, u,))
        conn.commit()
        newdata = database.execute("SELECT * FROM logs where loguser=? ", (u,)).fetchone()
        print "New Data:"
        print newdata
conn.close()
```

Output will be:

```
exist
Old Data:
HI
New Data:
(u'2006-01-05', u'HI message.content ', u'Zero', 100.0, 35.14)
```

As you can see, the `HI` has been updated with new data `HI message.content`.